# Background image for button not loading in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio

I have an android application with a main menu containing buttons with a background image

Code:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="300sp"
    android:layout_height="45sp"
    android:background="@drawable/aqua"
    android:text="This is a button"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"

    />
```

The image loads up in android above 5.0 but does not load up in android Kitkat and jellybean. I'm using android studio.

Comment: In what layout directory do you have the drawable?

Comment: use ImageButton. set src to backgroud drawable

Answer (score 0):

consider using a lower resolution drawable. it might just be that your file size is too big

Comment: In android studio there is only one drawable folder.

Comment: Can you post this is as a comment?

Comment: @AmanSahil yourPackage explorer view type at the top left might be set to "Android". Change it to "Project"